# Android Keyguard window doesn't display with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android

The Android Keyguard is created, everything seems to be working correctly but randomly(almost impossible to reproduce), the device thinks it's locked but the Keyguard window is not displayed. The only exception I see in the logs is this IllegalArgumentException below.  Does anyone know why this can occur where to start investing the root cause of this failure or how to remedy?

```
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager: Failed looking up window
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@413f34b0 is in session Session{413f2350 uid 1000}, not Session{416fb2f0 uid 1000}
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7444)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7426)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2646)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout(Session.java:173)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3679)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1278)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2535)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
00717 11-14 14:33:47.851   479   540 WRN WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$PolicyThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:825)
```